# how to count total number of divs inside another div using javascript

Tags: javascript

How to count the total number of `div` elements that are contained in another `div` using javascript?

Comment: You weed out a lot of JavaScript developers (sort of me too) when you don't include the jQuery tag!

Comment: @alex: So what? This has nothing to do with jQuery, and the OP may not be in a situation where he can use jQuery, or indeed he/she may not want to use jQuery. Frankly, for a non-jQuery question I'd rather not have the help of people who only look at questions tagged with jQuery and not with JavaScript.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `getElementsByTagName()` is not only a `document` method, but one that can run on any DOM element.

> **element**.*getElementsByTagName* is
> similar to
> **document**.*getElementsByTagName*, except
> that its search is restricted to those
> elements which are descendants of the
> specified element

see more at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName

---

So the actual code that does what you ask is

```
var container_div = document.getElementById('id_of_container_div');
var count = container_div.getElementsByTagName('div').length;
```

Comment: getElementsByTagName isn't available in browsers other than ones that use the Gecko engine. Try it in IE6.

Comment: I was pretty sure `getElementsByTagName` was in IE6?

Comment: @amphetamachine Then I wonder why this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536439(VS.85).aspx says "this feature needs Microsoft Internet Explorer 5 or later" ;) `getElementsByTagName` **is** available in IE6

Comment: Haha, random moment where IE6 doesn't fall over.

Answer (score 1):

You can use @davidcmoulton's handy Gist:
https://gist.github.com/davidcmoulton/a76949a5f35375cfbc24

I find it quite useful that it doesn't only count DIVs but also lists the count of all element types of your page.

Here is a copy of the Gist for further reference:

```
(function (window, undefined) {
//  Counts all DOM elements by name & logs resulting object to console. 
var forEach = Array.prototype.forEach,
counter = {},

incrementElementCount = function (elementName) {
  if (counter.hasOwnProperty(elementName)) {
    counter[elementName] += 1;
  } else {
    counter[elementName] = 1;
  }
},

processNode = function (node) {
  var currentNode = node;
  if (currentNode.nodeType === currentNode.ELEMENT_NODE) {
    incrementElementCount(currentNode.nodeName);
    if (currentNode.hasChildNodes) {
      forEach.call(currentNode.childNodes, function (childNode) {
        if (childNode.nodeType === currentNode.ELEMENT_NODE) {
          processNode(childNode);
        }
      });
    }
  }
};

processNode(window.document.firstElementChild);

console.log(counter);

}(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many way to count divs element using jquery.

But most popular and simple way are:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  var divCount = $("div").size();
  alert(divCount);
});
```

AND

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  var divCount = $("div").length;
  alert(divCount);
});
```

Its helpful for you