# How to get JavaScript function on a div which has multiple ids

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am implementing a discussion panel in ASP.net, in which I am assigning the comment id to the comments.

I want to call the jQuery `click` function on every comment click event. How I call the click function because in comment `div` I am assigning the ids 1,2,3.... and I don not know the range so I can not use `$("#1 || #2").click()`.

Comment: To get the number of div's look http://stackoverflow.com/a/10162596/1242357

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assign the same class to each of the comment divs and then do $(".commentdiv").click

jQuery is awesome like this.

If you need to know the id of the element that was clicked later, you can get it through this.id.

```
$(".commentdiv").click(function() {
   alert(this.id);
});
```

Comment: How to get the id of divs in jQuery click function?

Comment: How I can know which divs is clicked or the div has which id?

Answer (score 1):

Use [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

```
$(".panel").click(clickfunction);

function clickfunction()
{
    //do something
    id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In html add many divs like this

```
<div id="div1" onclick="Myfun(this)">
<div id="div2" onclick="Myfun(this)">
```

In javascript

```
function MyFun(currentDiv)
{
alert(currentDiv.id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assigning same class is the answer, If you want to count the number of divs then try this

var top_level_div = document.getElementById('id_of_first_div');

var count = top_level_div.getElementsByTagName('div').length;

The getElementsByTagName() is not only a document method, but one that can run on any DOM element.

```
element.getElementsByTagName is similar to document.getElementsByTagName, except that its search is restricted to those elements which are descendants of the specified element
```

I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2249702/1242357)